# Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion explanation

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone please explain the principle of inclusion and exclusion without using the definition of sets or union of sets by just giving a simple example ? Thanks.

Comment: Venn diagrams are a good way to understand the principle.

Comment: There are lots of good discussions online...[this discussion](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Principle_of_Inclusion-Exclusion) at the Art of Problem Solving looks like it has many examples.

Comment: okay  Thanks for the references :)